# Is there a way to detect if the user has clicked the scrollbar in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scrollbar

I am working on a react application, where i am using `window.addEventListener('mousedown', ...)` to detect if the user has clicked on the window. However i do not want this event to trigger, when the user clicks on the scrollbar. Is there a way to detect if the user has clicked the scrollbar?

I tried to detect the scrollbar by checking if `document.body.clientWidth < event.offsetX` inside of the `'mousedown'` event listener. Sadly, this did not work. I also tried to get the width of the scrollbar by [subtracting widths of certain elements](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/detect-if-a-page-has-a-vertical-scrollbar) expecting to get the width of the scrollbar. I also tried using the [react-scrollbar-size library](https://github.com/shawnmcknight/react-scrollbar-size).

This always resulted in the scrollbar having a width of 0px, and therefore it wasn't possible to detect if the user has clicked the scrollbar using this method.

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? If you attach the event listener to `document.body` rather than `window`, it wouldn't fire when clicking on the scrollbar and that doesn't require detecting the size of a scrollbar or detecting where it is (remember that it might also be on the *left* not just the right - some desktop environments in Linux offer this option).

Comment: Adding the event listener to `document.body` sadly doesn't seem to solve the issue. I covered just the solutions that seemed viable. I didn't manage to discover any other solution, otherwise i would have mentioned them in the question.

Comment: I hoped that there might be a more universal solution to this issue, which I am currently not aware of. I thought this is because of my lack of experience, rather than there not being a good solution to this problem, thats why I decided to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `click` event instead:

```js
window.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("click"));
```